# Throw own custom exception If MySql error occurs using MyBatis with annotations

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, psql

Heres my problem. I am using mybatis using annotations. For doing that I have created my own mybatis Interface and now I want to throw my own custom exception if anything goes wrong executing the query. Here is in code form what I exactly mean.

Consider the following interface I use to encapsulate some SQL queries:

```
 public interface MyMapper { 

      @Select("SELECT id, title, description, creationDate, modificationDate, owner_id AS \"owner.id\" "
        + " FROM article WHERE article_id = #{id}")
Article getArticle(int id);//If this fails I want my own custom Exception to be thrown

 }
```

As commented if I have a problem with my query or somehow the execution of getArticle(int id) fails I want it to throw my own custom exception not an IBatisException.If that is not possible by can someone suggest the tree hierarchy for Exceptions Since knowing the tree hierarchy would also help me know what all exceptions I can catch. Unfortunately I can't even catch a SqlException if something goes wrong. Only IBatisException and Exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I'd wrap every call to MyMapper in DAO instance and keep out exception hierarchy in specific place(ExceptionHandler):

```
public class MyDAO {
    MyMapper mapper;

    public Article getArticle(int id) {
        try {
            return mapper.getArticle(id);
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {//IbatisException is deprecated
            throw ExceptionHandler.handle(e);
        }
    }
}
```

try/catch clause probably would be duplicated in every method, so using Java proxy or [AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346750/how-to-re-throw-exception-in-aspectj-around-advise) to refactor exception handling functionality might be an option.
It might be possible to use load time weaving and weave around mapper itself instead of DAO. But I'd stil prefer DAO to leave myself room to extend functionality.
Regarding exception hierarchy MyBatis already has exception [hierarchy](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.2.7/org/apache/ibatis/exceptions/PersistenceException.java?av=f) of it's own. And in case your are using Spring, it has it's own data access exception hierarchy, so you might try out MyBatis-Spring integration. But as [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html) states, base DataAccessException is

> Root of the hierarchy of data access exceptions discussed in Expert
>   One-On-One J2EE Design and Development

So you might try to implement something similar based on the aforementioned book.